# Kafka consumer ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

*(Before start question, my English might not be enough to describe all clearly. Kindly let me know if you don't understand.)*

I am trying to send an data object from A spring project(producer) to B spring project(consumer) by Kafka.

Problem is that data objects in A and B are having different classpath. So B project data class is not able to map A project's field.

But two objects have same fields. So i want to get object from A project as an argument on B project.

**Error message**

```
Listener failed; nested exception is 

org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.DeserializationException: failed to deserialize; nested exception is 

org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [com.example.springboot.DTO.kafka.PostViewCountDTO]; nested exception is 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.springboot.DTO.kafka.PostViewCountDTO
```

**build.gradle**

```
    implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.8.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:2.8.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.3'
```

**Data class** (using A and B projects)

```
public class PostViewCountDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotNull
    private long postNo;
}
```

**producer config**

```
@Configuration
public class PostViewProducerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServer;

    @Bean
    public Map<String,Object> postViewProducerConfigs() {
        return JsonSerializer.getStringObjectMap(bootstrapServer);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, PostViewCountDTO> postViewCountDTOProducerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(postViewProducerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, PostViewCountDTO> postViewDTOKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(postViewCountDTOProducerFactory());
    }
}
```

**Common JsonSerializer class**

```
public class JsonSerializer {

    static Map<String, Object> getStringObjectMap(String bootstrapServer) {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer.class);

        return props;
    }
}
```

**consumer config**

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PostViewConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServer;

    @Bean
    public Map<String,Object> postViewConsumerConfigs() {
        return JsonDeserializer.getStringObjectMap(bootstrapServer);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, PostViewCountDTO> postViewCountDTO_ConsumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(postViewConsumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, PostViewCountDTO> postViewCountListener() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, PostViewCountDTO> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(postViewCountDTO_ConsumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public StringJsonMessageConverter jsonConverter() {
        return new StringJsonMessageConverter();
    }
}
```

**produce**

```
    @Async
    public void sendPostNo(PostViewCountDTO postViewCountDTO) {
        postViewKafkaTemplate.send(topic_viewCount, null, postViewCountDTO);
    }
```

**consume**

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = topic_viewCount, groupId = groupId, containerFactory = "postViewCountListener")
    public void consume(@Payload PostViewCountDTO postViewCountDTO) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean objects have different "paths"?

Comment: You need to add type mappings to the serializer and deserializer

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#serdes-mapping-types

Comment: OneCricketeer /// Sorry, My english is not good enough to describe this clearly. What i meant to say "path" is "package name".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add type mappings to the serializer and deserializer

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/serdes.html#serdes-mapping-types

On the producer side, map `com.a.PostViewCountDTO` to `PostViewCountDTO`.
On the consumer side, map `com.b.PostViewCountDTO` to `PostViewCountDTO`.

Comment: Thank you so much Gary! I have struggled this problem for two weeks. You just saved me.

Comment: @YeonCheolJang can you please show how you did the mapping? I am having the same problem

Comment: @Gloria - see the link in the answer; they just go in the producer/consumer configuration properties; if there is something you still don't understand, ask a new question showing your code and config.

Comment: @GaryRussell I posted a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70206790/how-to-map-types-using-properties-file-in-kafka . Please, if you can help.. I really don't know how to solve this.

Comment: @GaryRussell the link you have given is broken, if possible, please update it, so that people will get more context on it.

Comment: The link is fixed.