# How to map types using properties file in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have 2 spring boot applications. I am trying to map in the application.properties file in such way that the Consumer can receive the message send by the producer. I want to add that I am using a CustomMessage:

```
public class CustomMessage {

   private LocalDateTime timestamp;
   private Integer sensor_id;
   private Double measurement_value;
// getters and setters
}
```

My application.properties file for the producer:

```
# other properties ( I use CloudKarafka )
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer= org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer

spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=customMessage:assignment2.kafka.CustomMessage,customMessage:ro.tuc.ds2020.kafkaconsumer.CustomMessage
```

And for consumer:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer= org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=customMessage:ro.tuc.ds2020.kafkaconsumer.CustomMessage, customMessage:assignment.kafka.CustomMessage
```

I am not sure how the type.mapping should be done. Doing in this way presented, I get the following error:

```
Failed to construct kafka consumer
Failed to load: assignment.kafka.CustomMessage for  customMessage
```

It is also failing to construct producer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The map is from a class to a token (producer side) and token to class (consumer side).

You are mapping 2 different types to the same token.

Producer:

```
customMessage:assignment2.kafka.CustomMessage,
customMessage:ro.tuc.ds2020.kafkaconsumer.CustomMessage
```

Consumer:

```
customMessage:ro.tuc.ds2020.kafkaconsumer.CustomMessage, 
customMessage:assignment.kafka.CustomMessage
```

Assuming the producer's class is `assignment2.kafka.CustomMessage` you just need

```
customMessage:assignment2.kafka.CustomMessage
```

on the producer side and

```
customMessage:ro.tuc.ds2020.kafkaconsumer.CustomMessage
```

on the consumer side.

Comment: Oh ok it makes sense now. So I corrected the mapping as you said. But now it gives me another error, it says that : `The class 'assignment2.kafka.CustomMessage' is not in the trusted packages: [ro.tuc.ds2020.kafkaconsumer, ro.tuc.ds2020.kafkaconsumer.*]. ` This is happening on the consumer side

Comment: I tried to do this:  spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*  to trust all packages but it is not working. I think because I have another spring app for the producer and the custom message is there.

Comment: It shouldn't be creating an `assignment2.kafka.CustomMessage` if the configuration is correct, it should be creating a `ro.tuc.ds2020.kafkaconsumer.CustomMessage` so something else is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you have some old records in the topic that were sent before the latest config changes? You should be able to consume them by adding a second mapping on the consumer side `assignment2.kafka.CustomMessage:ro.tuc.ds2020.kafkaconsumer.CustomMessage`.

Comment: I think I do have some old records send. I wil try again

Comment: It worked!!! I had to delete my topic containing old records. Now it's working. Thank you so much!!

Comment: This question help me as well, thanks @Gloria

Comment: @GaryRussell would you be so kind to clarify what the `token` term means in the documentation for type mapping?

Comment: It's just a key to map the source class to some simple value and to map it back to a destination class name on the consumer. In this answer, the token is `customMessage` which is mapped from/to the relevant classes. The token can be anything; it just needs to be the same on each side.

Comment: @GaryRussell
is there a link to look at how the mapping is done from the config class? I too have the same problem. I was looking at the other post and the link in that post is not working. It is giving 404. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#serdes-mapping-types

and also I have posted my question here 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77804089/unable-to-deserialize-events-from-spring-boot-consumer-getting-an-error-even-aft

Comment: I no longer work on the project; here is the corrected link for the new docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/serdes.html#serdes-mapping-types