# How to deserialize message in consumer when produced message is a model type which consumer has no reference to?

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to deserialize a message produced from a service outside of conumers scope.
In case that package of serialized/deserialized model is different," kafka model is not in the trusted packages" error occurs.

So I think I have 2 options. Either produce a message as json/string or have consumer include producer library and use the same model to deserialize the message.

I wanted to manually ignore header type of message when deserializing in consumer but I have not managed to do that. Is there any way to do this or am I stuck with the two options described above?

Comment: You can override the default value type of the messages in Kafka using the property `JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE` of consumer factory and adding that to trusted packages list

Comment: Yes but the issue is that I do not have access to that package. Model is within a package outside of scope of consumer.

When I create the exact same model in the consumer..same fields and name, but 
 then different package name causes the exception.

Comment: You need to provide type mapping information or set the default type to the consumer's version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the default type to be the consumer's version and set `JsonDeserializer.USE_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS` to false.

Or, you need to provide type mapping https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#serdes-mapping-types

See this answer for an example: [How to map types using properties file in Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70206790/how-to-map-types-using-properties-file-in-kafka/70206854#70206854)

Comment: What if you are a consumer, and you have a model: "hat:com.myhat.hat"
And then a message comes with a Heading type of: "com.example.myhat.hat"
But you do not have access to "com.example.*" model? It's outside your scope. 

No common library can be used to give consumer access. I think only option is to remove type from the header or serialize the message as String..

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#serdes-json-config `JsonDeserializer.USE_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS (default true): You can set it to false to ignore headers set by the serializer.`

Comment: Yes, that's what I was expecting. I am thinking of serializing it as a String. That way I can keep the utilities of metadata included in the header. USE_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS i guess removes all data from the header (like timestamp and other)

Comment: No; on the consumer side, it just tells the deserializer to ignore those specific headers that convey type information.

Comment: Oh, I see.. I'll stay with Json serializer/deserializer then. Thank you for the help Gary!!

Comment: @camel38 did you try mapping the source class to the target class in the consumer like this?
`spring.kafka.consumer.properties:`
  `spring.json.type.mapping: com.example.myhat.Hat:com.myhat.Hat`

Comment: @AlexA. Service receiving the message has no access to com.example.myhat.Hat.
Target class is defined in a service outside of consumers scope.

Comment: I know @camel38, but the key part is just a string that identifies the class in the header. You don't need to have that class in the consumer's code

Comment: @AlexA. but that class in the header is the class which will be used for deserialization of the object. Setting `JsonDeserializer.USE_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS` to false helps because it allows me to use custom deserializer. As soon as type is included in the header, that is the class which will be used for deserialization. At least that's what it seems like to me. I've tried many options. Maybe you can provide an example of this?

Comment: Specifically, "kafka model is not in the trusted packages" error occurs for me as soon as i have a target class in the headers.

Comment: Ah, do you mean by `com.example.myhat.Hat:com.myhat.Hat` that a class can be mapped to another class by using ":"?

Comment: Exactly; follow the link in the answer. We usually map from a class to a token on the producer side and from the token to another class on the consumer side; that way, the consumer knows nothing about the producer, but just mapping from one class to another on the consumer side will work too.

Comment: I see now, thank you @GaryRussell and @Alex! Love it!