# Spring Boot Kafka, package name in the message header

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have two services `eshop` and `eshop-notification-service`. Service `eshop` sends message: **Notification(String message, LocalDateTime timestamp)** to Kafka and `eshop-notification-service` consumes it.

For some reason during deserialization of the message, package name (`com.example.eshop.model.Notification`) from producer is saved in the message headers, as a result, deserialization on the consumer side is failing with the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [com.example.eshop.model.Notification]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.eshop.model.Notification
```

While the correct package path on the consumer side is: `com.example.eshopnotification`

How can I resolve this issue? Why package is saved in the message headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer - [How to deserialize message in consumer when produced message is a model type which consumer has no reference to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70216775/how-to-deserialize-message-in-consumer-when-produced-message-is-a-model-type-whi/70247782#70247782)

You can either use type mapping, or set the `USE_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS` property to false and set a default type.

You can also set this on the producer side:

`JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS` (default true): You can set it to false to disable this feature on the JsonSerializer (sets the addTypeInfo property).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/#json-serde

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct solution

Comment: But what happens in case if we have a lot of @KafkaListeners in our app, what is the common approach here?

Comment: Move the deserialization to the listener adapter - that way, the converter can infer the type from the method signature. Use a `ByteArrayDeserializer` and a `JsonMessageConverter`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#messaging-message-conversion and this sample https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/tree/main/samples/sample-01 which sends a `Foo1` and receives a `Foo2` with the type being defined in the listener method. Just add the converter as a `@Bean` and Boot will wire it into the container factory.

Answer (score 1):

try the mapping configuration as below in application.yml

```
spring: 
  kafka:
    consumer:
      properties:
        spring:
          json:
            type:
              mapping: "com.example.eshop.model.Notification:com.example.eshopnotification.Notification"
```

Comment: While this will work, usually, we map from a class to a token (e.g. `notification`) on the producer side and from the token to a class on the consumer side. That way, the consumer doesn't have to "know" the name of the producer's class; they just need to agree on the token.