# Unable to deserialize events from spring boot consumer getting an error even after using trusted.packages

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have my consumer setup, I can post the message successfully from the producer app.

here is my producer service method

```
@Service
public class KafkaMessagePublisher {
 private final KafkaTemplate<String,Object> template;
 public KafkaMessagePublisher(KafkaTemplate<String,Object> template){
        this.template = template;
    }
         public void sendEventsToTopic(Customer customer){
            CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, Object>> fut = template.send(topic, customer);
            fut.whenComplete(((result, ex) -> {

                if(ex== null){
                    log.info("sent Message=[ {} ] with offset=[ {} ]"
                            ,customer.toString(),result.getRecordMetadata().offset());

                }
                else{
                    log.error("Unable to send the message=[ {} ] due to =[{}]"
                            ,customer.toString(),ex.getMessage());
                }
            }));
    }


}
```

and here are my configs for producer app

```
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      bootstrap-server: localhost:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
#      properties:
#        spring:
#          json:
#            trusted:
#              packages: com.example.kafka.producer.dto.*

app:
  kafka:
    topic-name: TestTopic
    partitions: 2
    replicationFactor: 1
```

And I am trying to receive it from consumer app

here is my consumer app service class

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class KafkaMessageListner {
     @KafkaListener(topics = "${app.kafka.topic-name}",groupId = "con")
    public void consume(Customer customer){
        log.info("Consumer consume the message  >>>: {}",customer.toString());
    }

}
```

here is my consumer configs

```
server:
  port: 9292

spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-server: localhost:9092
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      properties:
        spring:
          json:
            trusted:
              packages: com.example.kafka.consumer.dto.*


app:
  kafka:
    topic-name: TestTopic
```

I have also tried below  trusted packages but no use

```
      properties:
        spring:
          json:
            trusted:
              packages: java.util, java.lang, com.example.kafka.consumer.dto.*
```

and finlally the Consumer class in both the apps

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@ToString
public class Customer {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String contactNo;
}
```

and I am getting deserialization errors all the time, not sure what I am missing here.

```
2024-01-11 21:46:52,729 [ERROR] [65592]:[org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer]: Consumer exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleOtherException(DefaultErrorHandler.java:192)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1934)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1365)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition TestTopic-1 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:309)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(CompletedFetch.java:263)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractFetch.fetchRecords(AbstractFetch.java:340)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractFetch.collectFetch(AbstractFetch.java:306)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1235)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1186)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1649)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1624)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1421)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1313)
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'com.example.kafka.producer.dto.Customer' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.example.kafka.consumer.dto.*]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:98)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:572)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:73)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:300)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
2024-01-11 21:46:52,731 [ERROR] [65594]:[org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer]: Consumer exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleOtherException(DefaultErrorHandler.java:192)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1934)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1365)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition TestTopic-1 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:309)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(CompletedFetch.java:263)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractFetch.fetchRecords(AbstractFetch.java:340)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractFetch.collectFetch(AbstractFetch.java:306)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1235)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1186)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1649)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1624)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1421)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1313)
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'com.example.kafka.producer.dto.Customer' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.example.kafka.consumer.dto.*]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:98)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:572)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:73)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:300)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
2024-01-11 21:46:52,731 [ERROR] [65594]:[org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer]: Consumer exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleOtherException(DefaultErrorHandler.java:192)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1934)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1365)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition TestTopic-1 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:309)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(CompletedFetch.java:263)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractFetch.fetchRecords(AbstractFetch.java:340)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractFetch.collectFetch(AbstractFetch.java:306)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1235)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1186)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1649)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1624)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1421)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1313)
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'com.example.kafka.producer.dto.Customer' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.example.kafka.consumer.dto.*]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:98)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:572)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:73)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:300)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
2024-01-11 21:46:52,733 [ERROR] [65596]:[org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer]: Consumer exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleOtherException(DefaultErrorHandler.java:192)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1934)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1365)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition TestTopic-1 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:309)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(CompletedFetch.java:263)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractFetch.fetchRecords(AbstractFetch.java:340)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractFetch.collectFetch(AbstractFetch.java:306)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1235)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1186)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1649)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1624)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1421)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1313)
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'com.example.kafka.producer.dto.Customer' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.example.kafka.consumer.dto.*]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:98)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:572)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:73)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:300)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
2024-01-11 21:46:52,733 [ERROR] [65596]:[org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer]: Consumer exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleOtherException(DefaultErrorHandler.java:192)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1934)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1365)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition TestTopic-1 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:309)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(CompletedFetch.java:263)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractFetch.fetchRecords(AbstractFetch.java:340)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractFetch.collectFetch(AbstractFetch.java:306)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1235)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1186)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1649)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1624)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1421)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1313)
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'com.example.kafka.producer.dto.Customer' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.example.kafka.consumer.dto.*]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:98)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:572)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:73)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:300)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you try with same code with a new topic? Is there any chance the topic you are using for testing have been used before?

Comment: Yes I did same behavior, I cleared it twice thinking the same, and created fresh topics too, it's giving me the same error. 
https://gitlab.com/kishore87jetty/kafkaconsumer

Answer (score 0):

Add following config in your `application.yml`:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=com.example.kafka.producer.dto.Customer
```

[Ref](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#messaging.kafka.additional-properties):

Comment: thank you for the solution.  I used it this way too,  no change.  I am still getting same error:


java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition myTopic-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by:

Comment: Can you print out the content of record, by handling the exception?

Comment: Can you enable   trust all (*) as suggested in exception. `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*`

Comment: Let me try above two, I will get back

Comment: I see this in consumer :

Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [com.example.kafka.producer.dto.Customer]

whereas my Customer class is in com.example.kafka.consumer.dto.Customer
Not sure where it is picking it from. I think this is the issue

Comment: I think I have fixed it: I have used a JSON converter method 
  @Bean
    public StringJsonMessageConverter jsonConverter() {
        return new StringJsonMessageConverter();
    }

with this, it was able to convert the message from the producer. Not sure if that has something to do with the above message or not but it did work for me.

Comment: Cool, happy to know. That means there was a problem in producer and it was causing the issue.

Comment: I added the above bean in consumer, the consumer was unable to deserialize. Not sure if  this will work if I use the same topic to push different types of messages i.e. different message dto object.

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/serdes.html#serdes-mapping-types but using the converter will work too. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/serdes.html#messaging-message-conversion