# Spring Kafka error: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer'

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Producer properties

```
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=127.0.0.1:9092
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

Consumer properties

```
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=127.0.0.1:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=user-group
server.port=8085
```

Consumer Service

```java
@Service
public class UserConsumerService {

    @KafkaListener(topics = { "user-topic" })
    public void consumerUserData(User user) {
        System.out.println("Users Age Is: " + user.getAge() + " Fav Genre " + user.getFavGenre());
    }
}
```

Producer Service

```java
@Service
public class UserProducerService {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate;

    public void sendUserData(User user) {
        kafkaTemplate.send("user-topic", user.getName(), user);
    }
}
```

Producer Config for creating topic

```java
    @Configuration public class KafkaConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public NewTopic topicOrder() {
            return TopicBuilder.name("user-topic").partitions(2).replicas(1).build();
        } 
}
```

Producer works well but Consumer gives error like

```
2021-12-06 21:45:50.299 ERROR 4936 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Consumer exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 
'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
    at
org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleOtherException(DefaultErrorHandler.java:149)
~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0] DefaultErrorHandler.java:149
    at
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1760)
~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1760
    at
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1283)
~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1283
    at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
~[na:na] Executors.java:539
    at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
~[na:na] FutureTask.java:264
    at
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Thread.java:833 Caused by:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error
deserializing key/value for partition user-topic-0 at offset 1. If
needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
    at
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1429)
~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na] Fetcher.java:1429
    at
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3400(Fetcher.java:134)
~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na] Fetcher.java:134
    at
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1652)
~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na] Fetcher.java:1652
    at
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1800(Fetcher.java:1488)
~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na] Fetcher.java:1488
    at
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:721)
~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na] Fetcher.java:721
    at
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:672)
~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na] Fetcher.java:672
    at
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1277)
~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na] KafkaConsumer.java:1277
    at
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1238)
~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na] KafkaConsumer.java:1238
    at
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211)
~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na] KafkaConsumer.java:1211
    at
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1507)
~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1507
    at
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1497)
~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1497
    at
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1325)
~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0] KafkaMessage
```

I am new to Kafka and trying to figure out why I'm getting this error.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that your consumer properties are correct? Please, show us really a `consumer` part and be sure that you use `Deserializer` there.

Comment: Sorry Artem, my mistake, just updated consumer properties

Comment: Thanks. All good now on that side. Can we see more in stack trace about that error? I believe it should report the `cause` of such a `SerializationException`...

Comment: Added more as i could, when i run consumer service in ide (vscode) ide freezes and does not let me even copy entire logs so I need to restart

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Does the error message not tell you anything?

> This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer

See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/serdes.html#error-handling-deserializer):

> When a deserializer fails to deserialize a message, Spring has no way to handle the problem, because it occurs before the `poll()` returns. To solve this problem, the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` has been introduced. This deserializer delegates to a real deserializer (key or value). If the delegate fails to deserialize the record content, the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` returns a `null` value and a `DeserializationException` in a header that contains the cause and the raw bytes. When you use a record-level `MessageListener`, if the `ConsumerRecord` contains a `DeserializationException` header for either the key or value, the container’s `ErrorHandler` is called with the failed `ConsumerRecord`. The record is not passed to the listener.
>
> […]
>
> You can use the `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` constructor that takes key and value `Deserializer` objects and wire in appropriate `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` instances that you have configured with the proper delegates. Alternatively, you can use consumer configuration properties (which are used by the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer`) to instantiate the delegates. The property names are `ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS` and `ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS`. The property value can be a class or class name. The following example shows how to set these properties:
>
> ```java
> ... // other props
> props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
> props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
> props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class);
> props.put(JsonDeserializer.KEY_DEFAULT_TYPE, "com.example.MyKey")
> props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class.getName());
> props.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE, "com.example.MyValue")
> props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "com.example")
> return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
> ```

With Boot:

```properties
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
```

Comment: thanks Garry, it allowed me to see real exception without freezing issue in ide finally. now i face  "Class not found" on consumer and i think your answer will help me to fix it too from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987866/kafka-consumer-classnotfoundexception

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my consumer was consuming a generic of the following

```
 @KafkaListener(
      topics = "${spring.kafka.topics.foo}",
      containerFactory = "foo")
  public <T extends DomainEvent> void listen(List<T> domainEvents, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) { 
   ...
}
```

And was complaining about this new subtype, `ChildFoo2`, that I added, which extends my DomainEvent. However, I had forgotten to add my new child class as a JsonSubType to my parent class.

So doing the following, was the real fix for my case

```
@JsonSubTypes({@Type(ChildFoo1.class), @Type(ChildFoo2.class)})
public class DomainEvent {
...
}
```